# Not able to see Approve and Reject buttons on Task form

Tags: 2010, workflow

I have a 2010 Approval Workflow with 4 approval processes.

3 of them  are working fine, but for a single approval process the Approve / Reject  buttons are not visible[image]

How can this be resolved?

Comment: I have the same issue with missing Approve and Reject buttons in a task. Task Outcome column is put the last. But still no buttons. Who solved the issue? Please, share the options. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I deleted the workflow. And redid it in a new approval workflow.
Make sure you copy and paste whatever logic across before you delete the workflow. The items(approved,reject) had reappeared and could be clicked on in the new approval workflow. Hope this was helpful.

Comment: Is there any other approach instead of re-creating the whole workflow?

Comment: Please see u/Steve Hulsberg's Answer below for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure "Task Outcome" is the last item in the column list. Once you do this, the buttons should appear.

[image: Column Order]

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue in the following way. Because this happened after some manipulations in SPD, I went there and edited Approval process. [image]

By adding Approve and Reject buttons manually into Task Outcomes (and set sequence manually as well):
[image]